# How would I apply a different text color to "useragent" in this line of code (html)?

Tags: html

`<a class="pointer" onclick='toggleId("optionsdrop", "uadrop");'> Set Useragent</a>`
This text is in a drop down menu for my website because the background interferes with the text: ib264.720ks2345mzk81ap0197.tk

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but I think you're just looking to change the foreground color of an anchor link? Like with css as `.pointer {color:red}` or just inline like `style="color:red"`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.